# Integrate Redis as Hibernate second level cache for an off platform oracle database using spring boot and cloud foundry

Tags: hibernate, caching, redis, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am working on an application which will be hosted on cloud foundry. It connects with Oracle database which is outside the cloud (Off Platform) through User Provided Service. Also I am using Redis that is also on cloud.

Now I want to use Redis as a second level cache for Oracle Database.

Can anybody guide me or share any reference application for the same?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis. It has an example here: https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis/tree/devel/hibernate-examples

Comment: This solution does not work with Spring boot 2.1.x Hibernate 5.3.x.